# Doing an svn up to get latest diff

Tags: svn

If I check out an SVN revision R, replace some `.cpp` and `.h` files (NOT `.svn` files) in the tree with the patched ones (e.g., replace `a.cpp` with `a.cpp` patched), and then do an `svn up`, will I get the precise diff from HEAD?.. assuming conflict resolution.

Comment: I don't think I have understood clearly what you want. Why not use a `svn diff -r R:HEAD`?

Comment: I checked out old revision R. Replaced a file a.cpp with a.cpp (patched). Then did an svn up. Now, will svn diff give me the exact diff from HEAD..

Comment: You just restated what you already wrote. Why would you do such a thing? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not. After `svn up` files from HEAD revision (changes from R:HEAD range) **will be merged** with you local changes in your WC

If you want to get diff for locally changed files and HEAD revision in repo, you have to

`svn diff FILENAME REPO/FILENAME`

Comment: No, I want the diff from HEAD.. so it can be checked in. That's why I did an svn up.